# Alarm Notification Data disappear after rebooting phone

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am building a notification app, that uses alarm manager to set multiple notifications to reminde user of daily tasks, when phone is On everything is good, but when a reboot the phone, the notification is showing up but the notification data are lost (for example notification content) those data are saved into intent from my first activity 
this is code bellow. (i have added permission and receive action to my manifest)please I need some help

```
public class add_rreminde extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private int notificationId=1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_rreminde);

    //buton ok
    findViewById(R.id.but).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.cancel).setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view){

    EditText remide=findViewById(R.id.edit);
    DatePicker date=findViewById(R.id.date);

    Intent intent=new Intent(add_rreminde.this,AlarmReciver.class);
    intent.putExtra("notificationId",notificationId);
    intent.putExtra("todo",remide.getText().toString());
    final int _id=(int)System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent alarmIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(add_rreminde.this,_id,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarm=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    switch (view.getId()){
        case(R.id.but):
            int day=date.getDayOfMonth();
            int month=date.getMonth();
            int year=date.getYear();

            //create date
            Calendar startDate=Calendar.getInstance();
            startDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
            startDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            startDate.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            Long alarmStartDate=startDate.getTimeInMillis();

            //setAlarme
            alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarmStartDate,alarmIntent);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case (R.id.cancel):
            alarm.cancel(alarmIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"canceled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }


}
  }
```

my reciver that push notification

```
public class AlarmReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //get id from notification id intent
    int notification =intent.getIntExtra("notificationId",0);
    String getMessage=intent.getStringExtra("todo");

    //when notification is opened open mainActivity
    Intent mainIntent=new Intent(context,add_rreminde.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,mainIntent,0);

    NotificationManager mynotificationManager=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //prepare notification
    Notification.Builder builder=new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.assistant)
            .setContentTitle("changer oil")
            .setContentText(getMessage)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    //notify
    mynotificationManager.notify(notification,builder.build());

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default, all alarms are canceled when a device shuts down. To
>   prevent this from happening, you can design your application to
>   automatically restart a repeating alarm if the user reboots the
>   device.

so you could add a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`

firstly:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

and:

```
<receiver android:name=".SampleBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

now you set alarm again when device reboot:

```
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // Set the alarm here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi sir, it still the same problem always getting the notification but data are lost.  in my receiver, I did set the alarm in the if condition but nothing has been changed